# StatusBarStyle for Full Screen UIViewController

Tags: ios7, fullscreen, statusbar, modalviewcontroller

I currently have a application that sets the status bar style to light content.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
```

This works as expected except for a full screen modal window. Here is the code to create the modal UIViewController:

```
@implementation PostCard
- (id)initWithToRecipients:(NSArray *)toRecipients subject:(NSString *)subject message:(NSString *)message isHTML:(BOOL)isHTML
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] && (self = [super init]))
    {
        self.viewController = [MFMailComposeViewController new];
        self.viewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [_viewController setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        [_viewController setSubject:subject];
        [_viewController setMessageBody:message isHTML:isHTML];

        self.viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
        self.viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Cannont send mail from current device.");
    }

    return self;
}
...
@end
```

The postcard's view controller is then presented as

```
[myOtherViewController presentViewController:myPostCard.viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In full screen mode, the `statusBarStyle` reverts to dark content. If I change the `modalPresentationStyle` to `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`, the light content is preserved.

Is there a way to programatically set the 'statusBarStyle` of a modal window? Or tell it to inherit from the presenting UIViewController? Or is this a bug? (Note, I've also tried setting my project properties as well without success.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```